# jQuery filtering & sorting of tables - how to look "inside" html tags

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am making use of a [tablesorter library](http://tablesorter.com).  My issue is that every item in a cell inside of my table is a link, and the library starts sorting things incorrectly because it's looking at the HTML inside the cell, instead of the text.  In other words, in the following cell contents;

`<a href="ledger.php?var=345345">$100.64</a>` it sorts on:

`<a href="ledger.php?var=345345">` instead of `$100.64`

I know there are ways to look at the text inside of cells.  I started with the simple method that they have listed on the website, [text extraction method](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html).  However, I can't for the life of me get this to function properly.

Using my JS code, can anyone tell me how to apply this text extraction properly?  This is what I have now (below).

The current results of this code, when the "text extraction" line is NOT commented out, is that the plugin fails to load, and all jQuery on the page fails with it.  The console error in web developer plugin is:

> Error: node.childNodes[0].childNodes[0] is undefined Source File:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
            // TableSorter
                $("#dt-results") 
                .tablesorter({
                                widgets: ['zebra'], 
                                sortList: [[0,1]],

                                // define a custom text extraction function 
                                textExtraction: function(node) { 
                                    // extract data from markup and return it  
                                    return node.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML; 
                                } 
                })
                .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})
                .tablesorterFilter({filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                              filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                              filterCaseSensitive: false,
                              filterWaitTime: 100});
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you share some HTML?... just one row should be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, why don't you use `text()`? See http://api.jquery.com/text/

```
textExtraction: function(node) {
    return $(node).text();
}
```

Comment: this is close...  On one of my columns I have HTML for a link, and HTML for a <span style=""> to change the color of the text as well.  This one is not sorting correctly.  Any idea to get inside of that?

Comment: I guess the sorting should depend only on the text inside the `<a>` Tag? If you have at least one in every row, you can use this: `$(node).find('a').text();`

Comment: actually it isn't getting inside of the HTML that's the problem, it looks like it isn't sorting dollar numbers correctly at all...  They are in the format for money like:  100.34 and 3.63 and .34

Comment: Is the text extraction not working correctly or is the tablesorter doing mistakes?

Comment: yours was a fix for text extraction, to my knowledge.  This is the tablesorter as far as I can tell (even without the text extraction, and with no HTML, it still sorts wrong...)

Comment: This should work, maybe try setting the `debug` mode to `true` and see if it is setting the parser for that column to "currency".

Comment: @fudgey can I just tell it that the column is currency manually somehow?  How can I read what the parser is using, once in debug mode?

Comment: All - got the fix!  Fudgey you helped as well...   I added this: `headers: { 
         1: { 
          sorter:'currency' 
         } 
        },`

Comment: For the benefit of others, when you set the `debug` mode to `true` it outputs a lot of information into the console log. For Firefox, use the Firebug addon; for Chrome, press Ctrl-Shift-J; for IE press F12 and go to the console.